# Number of zeros that $z^4-5z+1$ has on the annulus $\{z | 1 < |z| <2 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a trivial question, but I'm very inexperienced with Rouche's theorem.

I need the number of zeros that $z^4-5z+1$ has in the annulus $\{z | 1 < |z| <2 \}$

I applied Rouche's theorem for functions $g(z)=z^4-5z+1$ and $f(z)=-5z$, and I got that $g$ has one zero in the unit disk and one zero in the disk of radius 2 and therefore no zeros in the annulus. However WolframAlpha says otherwise. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment but people looking for a good explanation check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/376348/388793).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help: On $|z|=2,$

$$|(z^4-5z+1)-z^4| < |z^4|.$$ On $|z|=1,$

$$|(z^4-5z+1)-(-5z+1)|< |-5z+1|$$

Comment: Why does the first inequality hold?

Comment: What about it is mysterious?

Comment: Oh yes it's obvious actually. I'm just too tired to think properly.

Comment: @zhw. was the answer 3 zeroes? On $\vert z \vert = 1$ I used $z^4+1$ as my "little" function and $-5z$ as my "big" so I get 4-1 = 3 zeros?